# Moment JS Returning Incorrect Value

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am having some issues with the Moment JS NPM. I have a date in the past set to Jan 31st for testing. It is returning as 1 from today's date. Take a look at my code and screenshots below:

```
var tz = -5,
   thisYear = moment().utc(tz).year(),
// plus one because Moment starts month at 0
   thisMonth = moment().utc(tz).month() + 1,
   today = moment().utc(tz).date(),
   thisHour = moment().utc(tz).hour(),
   start = moment([2015, 1, 31, 15]),
   now = moment([thisYear, thisMonth, today, thisHour]),
   daysPast = now.diff(start, 'days');

console.log(thisYear, thisMonth, today, thisHour);
console.log(2015, 1, 31, 15);
console.log(daysPast);
```

This is what is getting returned in the console:

[image]

When I change the date to the first of February, it returns correctly:

[image]

Anyone have any ideas why Moment is returning incorrectly with the past month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify zerkms answer, where you have:

```
thisMonth = moment().utc(tz).month() + 1,
```

you are setting *thisMonth* to 2 (if run in Feburary), then when you do:

```
start = moment([2015, 1, 31, 15]),
```

you are creating a date for 31 February, which doesn't exist so a date for 3 March is created.

Then when you do:

```
now = moment([thisYear, thisMonth, today, thisHour]),
```

remember that you incremented *thisMonth* by one, so it creates a date for 4 March, not 4 February (i.e. a month number of 2 creates a date for March).

The difference between 3 March and 4 March is one day.

Comment: That makes sense. Any idea on a solution? If I drop the plus 1? Edit.... that didn't work. lolz!

Comment: Yes. You increment the month number for human convenience, but don't restore the value for use with Date.

Comment: Ok, I did that. I took the user input date and subtracted the month by one. It seems to be working right now for a date that isn't the 31st, but I will let you know if it works when I go back to testing the 31st. Thanks again.

Comment: "and subtracted the month by one" --- you cannot do that

Comment: @zerkms, I can do that. The user is inputing the month 1 for January. As we talked about above, January in JS or Moment would be 0. Therefore to match the standard of JS or Moment I subtracted 1 from the user input and let the Moment month be. It is working and tested.

Comment: @Max Baldwin: no you cannot, since "add 1 month" is something more complicated than `month--` and I thought your current mistake revealed it to you. Seems like it was not enough. Okay, `31 March`, `month--`, `31 February`. Okay. "It is working and tested." --- if it worked - you wouldn't ask this question.

Answer (score 4):

In js months start with 0. So `2015, 1, 31` == `31st of February`

Which is interpreted as `March, 3rd` which is exactly one day behind `March, 4th`

If you want to manipulate with dates - use the corresponding momentjs methods instead: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/

Comment: I understand that, but I add 1 to the moment() month value. Therefore Jan would be zero, but I add one to it. It is working for the month of February. You can see that in the second screenshot.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin on the second screenshot you don't have February, but March. "but I add 1 to the moment() month value" --- no you don't. You just increment the month value. From `0` to `1`. You cannot just add an arbitrary number to a month and expect it to work, for this very reason: there are just 28 days in February. If you want to manipulate with dates - use the corresponding methods: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/